# Create an AJAX coupon code button on checkout step

Tags: magento2, checkout, ajax

I have a step added to checkout where i want to put some pre defined coupon codes buttons so the user can just click a button to apply the code if they want a sample for example.

For now I can apply a coupon with below form however causes a page reload on checkout:

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form-ajax" action="/checkout/cart/couponPost/" method="post">
    <input id="coupon_code" class="input-text" name="coupon_code" type="hidden" value="FREESAMPLE" /> 
    <button class="action apply primary" type="submit" value="Apply Discount"> 
        <span>Free Sample</span> 
    </button>
</form>
```

The checkout however has a much more elegant ajax version of applying a coupon code however and was wondering how i could harness this functionality?

I have tried with some standard jquery like below:

```
$(document).on("submit", '#discount-coupon-form-ajax', function(event) {  
      event.preventDefault(); 
      $.ajax({ 
        url:"/checkout/cart/couponPost", 
        type:'POST', 
        data:'ajax=true&'+$('#discount-coupon-form-ajax').serialize(), 
        success:function(data) 
        { 
            console.log(data);
        } 
      }); 
    });
```

This however was for Magento 1 I believe and does not respond in json and just seems to respond a standard checkout page. Not sure how to get the coupon controller to respond in json or however it normally responds or if this is possible anymore with code like above.